# How yo create a pattern for string match and how to get other arguments from the string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I don't know how to create a regular expression. I wanted to get subtrings from a string. In my case the string is `[_formatdate_form_date "D, d M y"]`. I wanted the field name `form_date` and the string between the double quotes i.e. `D, d M y`. I searched for the PHP functions like preg_match but all requires a pattern. So how to create a pattern for this

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a place to request private tutorials. I suggest you read one of the many "getting started" tutorials dealing with regular expressions. Also online regex utilities are a great help to play around. And there are really good books about that topic too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
$str = '[_formatdate_form_date "D, d M y"]';
$regex = "/_formatdate_(.*)\s\"(.*)\"/";

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

And the result `$matches` :

[image]

So to acces you have to do : `$matches[1][0]` or `$matches[2][0]`

But to understand what does it make, I suggest you to learn a minimum about regular expression : [Learn Regular Expression](https://regexone.com/)